# How are Linux ACLs different for files versus sockets

Tags: linux, access-control-list, socket, umask

With umask 0022, using default ACL entries default:user::rwx, default:group::rwx, default:mask::rwx and default:other::rwx for a directory, files created with touch (e.g.) have a mask of rw, and sockets created with nc -lU (e.g.) have a mask of r-x — why?